# Filtering dictionary with multiple possible comparisons

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm developing a website, that in part takes a json dictionary, in which every item has the keys "coder", "category" and alike inside of it, and takes certain url parameters to filter it by the name of the category, or the name of the coder. These URL parameters can be none if the user is not filtering, and can be partial if the user only filters specific information.

However, I can't figure out a clean way to filter the dictionary by these values.
What I expect to be able to do is to pass the value of "coder" and "category", and create a new dictionary with everything that matches the specified inner values in it, and return the entire dictionary as is if no arguments are specified.

Here's some code I have right now:

```
def filter_packages(packages, developer=None, category=None):
newpackages = []
for package in packages:
    if developer and category:
        if package["coder"] == developer:
            if package["category"] == category:
                newpackages.append(package)
    elif developer:
        if package["coder"] == developer:
            newpackages.append(package)
    elif category:
        if package["category"] == category:
            newpackages.append(package)
    else:
        newpackages.append(package)

return newpackages
```

This code is not viable because it's messy, long, and repetitive. The more filters users are able to apply, the more cases I would have to add.
I want to know how I can accomplish this with cleaner and more scalable code.

Comment: is the return in the for-loop intended? or should this just append and then return once all packages have been iterated over?

Comment: @sim ah it was not intended, forgot to remove it while clarifying it for this question.

Comment: I think you should go with Specification Design Pattern, which is particularly design to handle this scenario. The main advantage of that will be, if you decide to add more filters then instead of rewriting everything, you just need to extend the class for new filter type. This design pattern specifies the use of OCP from 5 solid design principles. You can find many sources on web to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that makes one assumption: The keyword arguments you pass in have the same name as the dictionary keys (that is not the case in your example, but you could adapt that with a map that takes the keyword argument name and outputs the dictionary key name - personally, I would rather adapt the names of your keyword arguments to match the dictionary keys).

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def build_dictionary_filter_from_kwargs(**filter_kwargs):
    def _filter_fun(field, value):
        return lambda d: d[field] == value
    return [_filter_fun(k, v) for k, v in filter_kwargs.items() if v is not None]

def filter_packages(packages, **filter_kwargs):
    new_packages = []
    filters = build_dictionary_filter_from_kwargs(**filter_kwargs)
    for package in packages:
        if len(filters) == 0 or reduce(operator.and_, [filter_(package) for filter_ in filters]):
            new_packages.append(package)
    return new_packages
```

Examples:

```
filter_packages(packages=[{"developer": "foo",
                           "package": "bar"},
                          {"developer": "foo2",
                           "package": "bar"}],
                package="bar",
                developer="foo")

# [{'developer': 'foo', 'package': 'bar'}]

filter_packages(packages=[{"developer": "foo",
                           "package": "bar"},
                          {"developer": "foo2",
                           "package": "bar"}],
                package="bar")

# [{'developer': 'foo', 'package': 'bar'},
#  {'developer': 'foo2', 'package': 'bar'}]
```

Conjunctions are arbitrarily stackable, so it is extendible.

Edit: On how it can be used:

```
import requests
packages = requests.get("https://api.oscwii.org/v2/primary/packages").json()

filter_packages(packages,
                coder="Danbo",
                downloads=0)
```

It should work without adjustments to your current function signature (other than renaming the `developer` argument to `coder`. Of course, in the implementation above you can only support checks for equality (and logical conjunction). For more complex filtering criteria you could indeed look at the specification design pattern as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Could you add some elaboration on how I could get this to work with my case? To make it clearer, the json dictionary I'm working with can be found here: https://api.oscwii.org/v2/primary/packages

Comment: added an example based on the package list.

Comment: this seems to work, thank you! Only one semi off topic question: do you know how could I go about treating "" (empty string) as None? Because under certain conditions, this is what Flask returns when a url parameter is not specified.

Comment: you can just change `return [_filter_fun(k, v) for k, v in filter_kwargs.items() if v is not None]` to `return [_filter_fun(k, v) for k, v in filter_kwargs.items() if v]`, then `None` and also the empty string will not produce a filter criterion.

Answer (score 1):

You can take in the filtering keys as a map:

```
def filter_packages(packages, filter_keys_map):
  newpackages = []
  for package in packages:
    num_matching_keys = 0
    for key, val in filter_keys_map.items():
      if package[key] == val:
        num_matching_keys += 1
    if num_matching_keys == len(filter_keys_map):
        newpackages.append(package)
  return newpackages   


filter_keys_map = {}
filter_keys_map["coder"] = developer
filter_keys_map["category"] = category
# Make sure to not have a dict entry with null value; in that case remove its key entirely.
filter_packages(packages, filter_keys_map)
```

Comment: this does not produce the correct results. if both coder and category are provided, then both must match for a package to be added.

Comment: in addition to what's stated in the above comment, it also doesn't return any packages in case both coder and category are not specified.

Comment: @sim I thought only 1 of them has to match for the package to be included; that's why I added `continue`. Fixed it.

Comment: @GuyTwig Fixed it.